# How to programmatically configure a Git branch's description?

Tags: git, config, stdin, git-branch, heredoc

The `git branch --edit-description` command opens a text editor for the user to manually enter the description of Git's current branch.

What I am after is something like:

```
git config branch.my_branch.description < <(fmt --width=72 <<MY_DESCRIPTION
Subject (50 chars max)

Intro (one sentence, line wraps after 72 chars)

Description (multiple paragraphs, line wraps after 72 chars)
MY_DESCRIPTION
```

According to the manpage `git config --file=config-file` is only for reading from or writing to a non-standard configuration file. Also the recent patch http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-config-git-config-from-file-handle-quot-quot-filename-as-stdin-td7603641.html does not aid in reading a configuration value from standard input.

Any ideas how to solve this problem in a simple way, ideally with Git built-ins? The latter is not a reqirement if that is not possible. Thanks for your valuable input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with `git config`.  The `--edit-description` option just sets `branch.branchname.description` in the default (local) git config file.

(The description is escape-sequence-encoded, but `git config` will do that for you.)

In shell-ese:

```
$ git config branch.my_branch.description 'Subject (50 chars max)

Intro (one sentence, line wraps after 72 chars)

Description (multiple paragraphs, line wraps after 72 chars)
MY_DESCRIPTION
'
```

does the trick.  If you have a description in a file, such as `/tmp/file`:

```
$ git config branch.my_branch.description "$(cat /tmp/file)"
```

does it.  Obviously you can replace `cat` with any other command, such as `fmt`, and you may use here-documents:

```
$ git config branch.my_branch.description "$(cat << END)"
some lines

of text

that wind up in the description.
END
```

(in my testing the encoded config entry for this last one does not end in a newline, but that seems to be OK, even though the other versions do end in a newline).

---

Edit: bash does not like the above here-document syntax; this seems to work:

```
cmd "$(cat << END
here-document text
goes here
END
)"
```

in both bash and /bin/sh, on my test system.

Comment: Your first and second suggestion works. The third one with `"$(cat << END)"` yields the following warnings with Bash version 4.2.45(1)-release: bash: "Warning: here-document at line 38 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `END')". The result of the third is an empty description.

Comment: @TimFriske: interesting, must be some variation in shells.  /bin/sh behaves OK, bash complains.  Will edit...